# java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, single-sign-on

I have two web-applications which need to run on Tomcat 6, MS SQL 2008 and JTDS-1.2.2 as driver.

If I start only one web application everything is working fine, but as soon as I start the second one I get the following error (it does not matter the order):

```
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library
```

Of course, the library `ntlmauth.dll` is under `C:\WINDOWS\system32`

It seems that the second application which starts is not able to find the `ntlmauth.dll` for the single sign on.

Comment: It hink the DLL may still be loaded and can't be loaded again into the other running instance. You may test this, by putting the DLL into the installation folder of your tomcat(s) and provide the path of that certain DLL to your app.

Answer (score 19):

I got past this by changing the url from

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host_server:1433/Database_name
```

to

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host_server:1433/Database_name;user=XXX;password=YYY
```

Apparently, "When URL [does] not contains user and password properties, systems uses Windows authentication method, and "SSPI Native library not found" error appears."

Comment: You just put an end to 3 hours of fruitless debugging.  Hooray!

Comment: Yeah, I think it took me a about that long to find the magic setting.

Comment: downvoted because parent is asking about SSO and this answer doesn't use SSO (Windows authentication) but SQL Server authentication instead, so doesn't solve the parent problem

Comment: Thank you for your upvote. @Jacob, I looked at the OP and he is not actually asking about SSO. I was not using/didn't care about SSO when I hit the error. The answer I gave got past the issue and on to something I did care about.

Comment: For me, this error appeared when i mistakenly supplied a blank username

Comment: It seems like a problem in SQL Server 2008 or above, I never got this problem in SQL Server 2005. It works for me now! Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

**This is the solution:**

Download the [jTDS driver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/latest/download), unzip it, and copy `x86\SSO\ntlmauth.dll` to `jdk\jre\bin`.

This should solve your issue.

**Edit:**

Without the JDK installed the path for me was `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\ntlmauth.dll`

*jTDS must be able to load the native SPPI library (ntlmauth.dll). Place this DLL anywhere in the system path (defined by the PATH system variable) and you're all set.*

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run two (or more) Tomcat applications on the same server that both access a SQL Server using the JTDS driver and windows authentication, a very helpful answer courtesy of Chris White is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637585/native-library-sqljdbc-auth-dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader).

Chris' answer has to do with sqljdbc_auth.dll, but the recommendations are the same for the JTDS driver and ntlmauth.dll:

1. Put ntlmauth.dll into the `tomcat 7.0\bin` directory. Actually, I believe you can put ntlmauth.dll into any directory in the system path, or the Java `jre\bin` directory.
2. Importantly, don't bundle the JTDS jar in the war file of any Tomcat application using the JTDS driver. Instead, put one copy in the `Tomcat\lib` directory, where Tomcat will load it and make it available to all apps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on 64-bit windows but running 32-bit java (the one in program files x86) then you need the 32-bit ntlmauth dll and not the 64 bit one that you might have expected.

Comment: Yes: there's more info here on deploying both 32 and 64-but DLLs to their correct locations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16429490/1073262