# How to make use of Trusted_connection property with jTDS driver?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string, jtds

I am using jTDS driver to connect to a SQL Server database. I don't want to provide my Windows Domain username and password but would like to make use of [Trusted_connection](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/trusted-connection/) property in my connection string. However it seems as per [this](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) jTDS driver FAQ page there is no property named `Trusted_connection`  supported by jTDS driver.

Given the application and SQL Server database are on the same host and I have `ntlmauth.dll` installed correctly, how do I take advantage of `Trusted_connection` property so that I don't have to specify username/password?

Is it that jTDS automatically makes use of Domain username and password as soon as it spots `useNTLMv2` and `domain` properties being used as shown in the following connection url?

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DBHostName:Port/DatabaseName;useNTLMv2=true;domain=DomainName
```

NB: I could test this myself if only I have access to the code of the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server - connect with windows authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682852/sql-server-connect-with-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the file [README.SSO](http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/code/HEAD/tree/branches/jTDS%201.3%20%28stable%29/README.SSO), you need not specify any credentials.

> In order to set up the jTDS driver to use Windows Single Sign On, users
>       will have to connect without providing a user name and password. This will
>       only work on Windows.
>
> Driver example:

```
    // No user name or password in URL or as parameters
    DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/LionKing");
```

You need not specify the useNTLMv2 parameter either, if you do it determines the version of NTLM that will be used, not IF NTLM will be used or not.

Comment: i'll upvote but how did you get passed this error: "Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property."

Comment: @Грозный See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733776/1973271